# XML Attribures Empty

Tags: python, xml

I'm reading an xml object into Python 3.6 on Windows 10 from file. Here is a sample of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <channel>
        <item>     
            <BurnLocation>@ 32 40 52.99 @ 80 57 33.00</BurnLocation>
            <geo:lat>32.681389</geo:lat>
            <geo:long>-80.959167</geo:long>
            <County>Jasper</County>
            <BurnType>PD</BurnType> 
            <BurnTypeDescription>PILED DEBRIS</BurnTypeDescription> 
            <Acres>2</Acres> 
        </item>
        <item>     
            <BurnLocation>@ 33 29 34.26 @ 81 15 52.89</BurnLocation>
            <geo:lat>33.492851</geo:lat>
            <geo:long>-81.264694</geo:long>
            <County>Orangebrg</County>
            <BurnType>PD</BurnType> 
            <BurnTypeDescription>PILED DEBRIS</BurnTypeDescription> 
            <Acres>1</Acres> 
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is a version of my code:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

local_filename = os.path.join('C:\\Temp\\test\\', filename)
tree = ET.parse(local_filename)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    for next1 in child:
        for next2 in next1:
            print(next2.tag,next2.attrib)
```

The issue I'm having is that I cannot seem to isolate the attributes of the child tags, they are coming up as empty dictionaries. Here is an example of the result:

```
   BurnLocation {}
   {http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#}lat {}
   {http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#}long {}
   County {}
   BurnType {}
   BurnTypeDescription {}
   Acres {}
   BurnLocation {}
   {http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#}lat {}
   {http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#}long {}
   County {}
   BurnType {}
   BurnTypeDescription {}
   Acres {}
```

I am trying to print out the items within the tags (i.e. Jasper), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print out the *node names*. Then you'll know at what level you are in your code. By the way, I just noticed that apart from the root declaration, none of your elements have attributes. That may actually explain things.

Comment: Yeah I've done that and it tells me I'm at the correct level starting with burn locations. I will update now.

Comment: I think you may be struggling with terminology. You got `<tag>` right, but an *attribute* is `<tag attribute-name="attribute value">`.

Comment: I understand, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is the [`text`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) contents of each element, and not their attributes.

This ought to do it (slightly simplified for a fixed filename):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    for next1 in child:
        for next2 in next1:
            print ('{} = "{}"'.format(next2.tag,next2.text))
        print ()
```

However, I'd simplify it a bit by:

1. locating all `<item>` elements at once, and
2. then looping over its children elements.

Thus

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')

for item in tree.findall('*/item'):
    for elem in list(item):
        print ('{} = "{}"'.format(elem.tag,elem.text))
    print ()
```